# MongoDB GroupBy Aggregate and Count Documents C#

Tags: c#, mongodb, linq, group-by, aggregate-functions

I have a requirement to get the count of documents based on status of customer. So I need to use aggregate function and then group by based on status. I have used following code for that but the problem is that in Result I am getting the list of documents but what I just want to have is the status and count of documents under that. Can any body please help in adjusting the query to achieve the results.

```
var result = collection.Aggregate()
                    .Group(
                        x => x.status,
                        g => new
                        {
                            Result = g.Select(x => new CustomerDetailsList
                            {
                                ActiveType = x.status,
                                Count = g.Count()
                            }
                             )
                        }
                    );
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: what if you try with        ActiveType = x.key,
                                Count = g.Count()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason you're getting a list of documents for every key is that you're running this nested `Select`, all you need is:

```
collection.Aggregate()
          .Group(
              x => x.status,
              g => new CustomerDetailsList
              {
                  ActiveType = g.Key,
                  Count = g.Count()
              }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

I am satisfied with the answer of [@mickl](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61355329/2159510) and it works well as I tested according to my requirement but here is the way I opted in my app as this is what I am comfortable with. The method is to use the collection as queryable

```
var result = collection.AsQueryable()
            .GroupBy(x => x.status)
            .Select(x => new CustomerDetailsList 
            { 
                ActiveType = x.Key, Count = x.Count()
            }).ToList();
```

I have used more LINQ in this way so I choose this as it's better to understand for me.

You can choose any of the methods either this or as demonstrated by @mickl